# Direct2D C++ the easiest way to draw bottom half of an ellipse

Tags: direct2d

I want to draw the bottom **half** of an ellipse. it better be portable. I would like to group several drawing commands in function and draw it in many places.

It would be better if not using bitmap kind of thing. I'd like the geometry cover less things as possible. Plus, it is more complicated. Still, it would be acceptable.

I am using C++ VS17 on Win10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create path geometry, then do Open()->sink->AddArc() (twice with appropriate parameters)->Close(). Now you have your geometry that you can draw.

Comment: I did that and get what I wanted. but this is not portable, right? although you can store the geometry, it's position is fixed when created.

Comment: Geometry is immutable, that's correct. To draw it at different coordinates you can use target/context transform around Draw*() call. I don't know what you mean by portable though.

Comment: I group it into a function like drawHouse() in which I draw the geometry. but I need to draw house at many coordinates. before this answer, I pass the coordinates into the function and draw it there using run-time parameters. But I am concerned about whether this method will take more time and resources. As what I see in the msdn example, they store brushes, bitmaps etc. So I wonder if I can create a geometry and save it so that next time I draw it, it is more efficient.

Comment: Sure, if it's possible to create it once, you should do that. To draw it at different coordinates use SetTransform() on target/context you're using to add offset you need.